# How to not render a component in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have table of player in html:     [table]

How I can hide or not render this table when it is empty? I try to add if conditional in java code and add this table to the page only if there is some value but then wicket throws an exception that he cant find component with this id. So how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws the exception because the html markup expects the component to exist. Ie you must add it.

If it's an entire panel you want to hide then using EmptyPanel is the will hide the entire panel.

You can also use component.setVisible(false) to hide it if its only one component in the panel.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the isVisible() function and return false if no date is available. But, this function will be called a few times, so if determining if data is available(like, hitting a database) you can call the setVisible(boolean) function.

Another option is to exchange the Repeater with an EmptyPanel if no data is available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same condition you already use in java, but instead of not adding the table to the page, use table.setVisible(false).

Another way to do it would be to override the setVisible() and isVisible() methods, but i don't think it is recommended (see [here](http://www.devproof.org/wicket_best_practice))

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

As the other users have pointed out, overriding isVisible() is not recommended because this function is called many times before component is rendered. 
You should instead override onConfigure() and put inside it the code that decides if your table must be visible or not. onConfigure() is called just once per request.